# Tengo una duda en C++

Tags: c++

Realize un codigo que me encrypta las vocales, lo tengo para que me guarde solamente 10 caracteres, pero cuando lo paso a 100 el sistema se bloquea. Cual podria ser la razon.?

```
             using namespace std;
               int main(){


string mensaje[10];
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
int k = 0;
string men[10];
string texto;

                cout<<"Ingrese los "<<endl;

            for(i=0;i<5;i++){
                cout<<"Texto:\n"<<endl;
                cin>>setw(10)>>texto;
                cin.clear();
                men[i] = texto;
                for(k=0;k<10;k++) {
                    if(texto[k] == 'a') {
                        texto[k] = '#';
                    } else if (texto[k] == 'e') {
                        texto[k] = '$';
                    }
                    else if (texto[k] == 'i') {
                        texto[k] = '%';
                    }
                    else if (texto[k] == 'o') {
                        texto[k] = '*';
                    }
                    else if (texto[k] == 'u') {
                        texto[k] = '&';
                    }

                }
            mensaje[i]=texto;

            }




        for(j=0;j<5;j++) {

                cout<<(j+1)<<"-Mensaje: "<<mensaje[j]<<" "<<men[j]<<endl;

        }

     return 0;
```

}

Cuando cambio los valores de 10 a 100, el programa falla. Los cambio de letras y simbolos estan bien, lo que falla es cuando cambio los caracteres que quiero.

Comment: Puedes colocar todo el código?

Comment: A ver si me queda claro: has puesto un código que **si funciona** para que te digamos el porqué falla cuando cambias algo. Yo no me dedico a esto ni nada, pero ... ¿ no habría sido mejor colocar el código que **no funciona** ?

Comment: ¿Ya modificaste el tamaño de las matrices y bucles de 10 a 100?

Answer (score 0):

El mejor consejo que te puedo dar es que debido a la repetición del 10 añadieses después del encabezado

```
 #define LONGITUD 10
```

Comment: No soluciona el problema reportado.